# How are largescale webapps like facebook upgraded live without affecting users at that moment

Tags: web-services, rest

I am creating a web app but the problem is, I keep getting new ideas for features as I code. How can I add this features later? I understand I can work with frameworks which I am doing e.g laravel and angularJs but my main question is, how do companies like facebook upgrade facebook live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can do it because the 'application' isn't hosted on a single server, it's distributed across thousands of servers around the globe, borken up into lots of individual microservices which are always being offered by multiple redundant nodes hidden behind load balancers which distribute the traffic across all the active nodes in the cluster.

They can do upgrades without affecting the live service by upgrading a single node at a time - take the node out of the cluster, upgrade it offline, return the node to the cluster. Rinse, repeat until all the nodes in the cluster are upgraded, at which point the new features become fully available.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Your answer is helpful, so now how can I keep adding new features to my webapp? Are the frameworks enough? since I would be using locally for the time being